# how can we avoid duplicate values in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing number of check boxes with delete ,add,view options  in database,
if you check on that options,it storing some values.But if i click again that will store again and again.
how to avoid this duplicate values

Comment: database table structure??? where is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the column containing unique value as `UNIQUE` or do a condition :

```
if SELECT Query return this value , don't insert , else insert.
```